# Python - Cbind previous and next row to current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have a Pandas data frame like so:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Which looks like:

```
  doc  sent col1 col2 col3
0   0    0    5   4    8
1   0    1    6   3    2
2   0    2    1   2    9
3   1    0    6   1    6
4   1    1    5   1    5
```

I'd like to bind the previous row and the next next row to each column like so (accounting for "doc" and "sent" column in my example, which count as indices that nothing can come before or after as seen below):

```
  doc  sent col1 col2 col3 p_col1 p_col2 p_col3 n_col1 n_col2 n_col3
0   0    0    5   4    8    0      0      0      6       3      2  
1   0    1    6   3    2    5      4      8      1       2      9
2   0    2    1   2    9    6      3      2      6       1      6
3   1    0    6   1    6    0      0      0      5       1      5
4   1    1    5   1    5    6      1      6      0       0      0
```

Comment: Your MWE dataframe does not have anything to do with the input you show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`pd.DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get the prev / next rows, [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to merge the dataframes & [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to set nulls to zero

The presence of nulls upcasts the ints to floats, since numpy integer arrays cannot contain null values, which are cast back to ints after replacing nulls with 0.

```
cs = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
g = df.groupby('doc')

pd.concat([
   df, 
   g[cs].shift(-1).add_prefix('n'), 
   g[cs].shift().add_prefix('p')
], axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

outputs:

```
   doc  sent  col1  col2  col3  ncol1  ncol2  ncol3  pcol1  pcol2  pcol3
0    0     0     5     4     8      6      3      2      0      0      0
1    0     1     6     3     2      1      2      9      5      4      8
2    0     2     1     2     9      0      0      0      6      3      2
3    1     0     6     1     6      5      1      5      0      0      0
4    1     1     5     1     5      0      0      0      6      1      6
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably end up using some variation of this. You mixed up "p" and "n" though. I can mark it as the right answer if you explain a way I can avoid taking the value of the previous and next row at the beginning and end, respectively, of a doc index.

Comment: thanks, will update the typo and code to group by `df.doc`